# Why is a pure Python negative binomial pmf so much faster than the scipy version?

Tags: python, scipy

scipy.stats has a function [nbinom.pmf()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html) which computes the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) of the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

The mathematical function is very easily described in pure Python code.

```
from math import comb
def nbinom_pmf(k, n, p):
        return comb(k+n-1, n-1)* p**n * (1-p)**k
```

It turns out that scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf() is quite a lot slower than this pure python code and this is a known issue due to the overhead of checking the parameters. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) suggest using ._pmf instead. This is indeed faster but is **still** slower than the pure Python code in many cases. E.g.

```
In [24]: %timeit nbinom_pmf(1, 26, 0.5)
282 ns ± 1.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit nbinom._pmf(1, 26, 0.5)
2.03 µs ± 6.55 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit nbinom._pmf(36, 26, 0.5)
2.03 µs ± 1.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit nbinom_pmf(36, 26, 0.5)
1.64 µs ± 30.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Why is the scipy code so much slower than the naive pure Python implementation?

Comment: FYI: There is a related discussion in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17973

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scipy call goes through several function lookups. I was checking out the github here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py
Every function call adds time and passes the data which costs time and dictionary lookups.

As Warren mentioned, there is discussion on this topic here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17973

In that post it is mentioned: "there is some overhead, so pure Python may be faster in the fastest cases."

Sure thing, the short of it is that function calls are not free. When you call a function at the lowest level, you'll push variables onto the stack, move the stack frame and then jump to your function. Python will be doing all of this at the interpreter level. It isn't free. You might check out: ilovesymposia.com/2015/12/10/the-cost-of-a-python-function-call where they discuss the cost of a function call. I'll add that anytime you look up an argument from the function call you are also doing a lookup in a dictionary where the key-value of the parameter is stored.

So, the more levels of functions that you go down, the more you'll have to pay in overhead to get to the underlying code that you care about.

Comment: Could you add some detail please?

Comment: Sure thing, the short of it is that function calls are not free. When you call a function at the lowest level, you'll push variables onto the stack, move the stack frame and then jump to your function. Python will be doing all of this at the interpreter level. It isn't free.  You might check out: https://ilovesymposia.com/2015/12/10/the-cost-of-a-python-function-call/ where they discuss the cost of a function call. I'll add that anytime you look up an argument from the function call you are also doing a lookup in a dictionary where the key-value of the parameter is stored.

Comment: So, the more levels of functions that you go down, the more you'll have to pay in overhead to get to the underlying code.